# Delete vcenter vm template from vsphere api

Tags: vmware, packer, vsphere

I m building an automated infrastructure and provisionning with terraform and ansible.

I use terraform with VMware vSphere Provider. Before creating infrastructure, i build a vm template  with packer and then use it as a base. But i m unable to destroy from terraform or the api vsphere as documented here :

https://vmware.github.io/vsphere-automation-sdk-rest/vsphere/index.html#PKG_com.vmware.vcenter

> operations > vcenter > vm_template

Is anyone find a way to delete a vm template with the vsphere api?

Currently i have to go through the vmware vsphere web client to delete a vm template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, as of today, there are no ways to delete a template (or even be able to modify the template back to a VM) through the vSphere Automation REST API. The web services API is the only way.