# Delete VMWare template via API

Tags: vmware

Same question as this:
[Delete vcenter vm template from vsphere api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60240774/delete-vcenter-vm-template-from-vsphere-api/69121762)

Though I don't know what a "web services" api means and my comment was deleted. Does it just mean the GUI? If so, there is no way to automate the deletion of templates? That seems insane to me. Are people keeping their templates around forever? Or manually deleting them when they're no longer required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be clear, the original question was in regards to using the vSphere Automation (REST) API. That API service has limited functionality in comparison to the vSphere Web Services (SOAP) API which historically has the most functionality. These are two separate API services.

- [vSphere Web Services API docs](https://code.vmware.com/apis/968)
- [vSphere Automation API docs](https://developer.vmware.com/docs/vsphere-automation/latest/)

Deleting templates are a two step process in the Web Services API due how the underlying virtual machine object has been defined.

1. Mark Template as VM with the [MarkAsVirtualMachine](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/b50dcbbf-051d-4204-a3e7-e1b618c1e384/538cf2ec-b34f-4bae-a332-3820ef9e7773/vim.VirtualMachine.html#markAsVirtualMachine) method
2. Delete the VM with the [Destroy_Task](https://vdc-download.vmware.com/vmwb-repository/dcr-public/b50dcbbf-051d-4204-a3e7-e1b618c1e384/538cf2ec-b34f-4bae-a332-3820ef9e7773/vim.ManagedEntity.html#destroy) method